# Unable to set the height for ngx-quill editor using angular flex layout

Tags: css, flexbox, quill, angular-flex-layout, ngx-quill

Unable to set the height for ngx-quill editor using angular flex layout.

The height of the editor (grey border) is overflowing the parent div (background in red).

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-98pc2t)

How to make sure the editor stays inside the parent div?

Comment: `[styles]="{minHeight: '250px'}"` the simplest way.

Answer (score 6):

**SOLUTION:**
All the solutions online wont work for some reason. Says something about 'unsafely set styles' and they do not even apply.

This solution overrides quill text area in Angular
(You can choose any CSS file, I just prefer all my Quill editors to be the same size)

*src/styles.scss*

```
.ql-container {
     height: 300px !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

solution was to override `height` in `ql-container` class -

```
.ql-container {
  height: auto;
}
```

[github link](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/issues/352#issuecomment-470916865)

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest `quill` and `ngx-quill`, and assuming you're OK using `::ng-deep`, this works:

```
::ng-deep .ql-editor {
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Or override with global scss since ng-deep is meh. 
This article can help: https://betterprogramming.pub/best-way-to-overwrite-angular-materials-styles-e38dc8b84962

Comment: Yes, I agree.  It is quite meh.  Honestly though, I'm also quite meh about global scss as well haha!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `height: 100%` coming from the `ql-container` class which causes the overflow.

Just add the following css to your code it will overwrite quill style

```
.ql-container {
  min-height: 10rem;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ql-editor {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).